# How to specify default MTA?

Tags: email, cron, mta

i'm trying to use the MAILTO function in crontab on my mybookworld (it's a nas)

I've installed a rather unfamiliar(in think) MTA: [esmtp](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/)

With mutt(console based email client) it works perfectly. But in crontab there is no reaction(even if i'm using the same crontab file as on my desktop machine with postfix as MTA). So i think maybe the system doesn't know that esmtp is a MTA that could be used from crontab.

How can i tell crontab what mta to use?

greetings

Comment: This question belongs on http://www.superuser.com

Comment: thanks for the hint. posted it there